# Which is faster? Electron close to the atom's nucleus or the one far from it and why?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, electrons

As we know when the distance between the atom's nucleus and the electron increase the energy of it increase but what about the speed, as physics say that the smaller the radius is the faster the body is, so does this apply to electrons or does the energy play a role in electron's speed?

Comment: What had you found before you asked,  while searching for the answer? What the law of energy conservation say ?

Answer (score 2):

When you deal with electrons bound in potentials with a particular mathematical form (inverse distance potentials, here for a Coulombic potential having the form $r^{-1}$) you can invoke the virial theorem,
$$2T=−U$$
as explained for instance [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/250114/why-is-kinetic-energy-total-energy-and-potential-energy-2-times-total).

Accordingly electrons more weakly bound to an atom (and therefore more shielded from the nuclear attraction, and further away on average) will have a higher potential energy (closer to zero, less negative) and the translational energy will therefore by smaller, too ($T>0$, $U<0$ for bound states). At the edge of the bound state, as the principal quantum number heads to infinity, the potential energy goes to zero, and so does the kinetic energy. It makes sense, since the electron would not remain bound if it had enough kinetic energy to overcome the attraction.

Comment: see also: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/119467/potential-energy-of-electron-in-excited-hydrogen-atom/119468#119468

Comment: and https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80922/what-kind-of-energies-are-present-in-an-electron/80938#80938